# How to create and import custom error messages file in angular 6+

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi I want to create a common file for my error messages for the application and then import it any where in the application. One idea I have is that I create a JS file with all the error messages and export using module.exports and then import that file. But I think there must be a typescript way of doing this I tried looking on google as well but could not find any thing. Should a I make a TS class with error messages as properties of that class and then Import that class?
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use i18n (which is designed for translation but it's ok for the working purpose you want - 1 language). [angular doc](https://angular.io/guide/i18n).

Also it's perfectly fine to do:

myErrors.ts:

```
export const ErrorMessages = {
   inputInvalid1: `something something something`,
   unkownError: `etc`
}
```

and import anywhere it's needed:

```
import { ErrorMessages } from 'myErrors'
```

Comment: I guess this what I needed. Thanks!